# Parsec permutation parser with separators

Tags: haskell, parsec

I want to parse assembly programs. I have a fixed format for parsing an assembly address: `[ register + offset + label ]` I implemented parsers for registers, offsets and labels. Now I want to create a parser which parses the whole address.

The combinations I want to accept:

```
[register]
[offset]
[label]
[register + offset]
[register + label]
[offset + label]
[register + offset + label]
```

And what I don't want to accept:

```
[]
[register offset]
[register + ]
...
```

Of course the simple solution is to have something like:

```
choice $ try (parseRegister >>= \r -> Address (Just r) Nothing Nothing)
       <|> try ...
```

But it is ugly and does not scale well with more types of elements. So I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: One lightweight trick is to use `Applicative` style and `optionMaybe`. Like this `try $ Address <$> optionMaybe parseRegister <*> optionMaybe parseOffset <*> optionMaybe parseLabel`.

Comment: That works with monadic style, too. But my main problem is that I have to parse those `+` signs

Comment: Oh! Those are the literal strings. You might want to use `sepBy` to get a list of strings and then compute your `Address` value from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reorder your table, you see it’s a series of choices:

```
[register + offset + label]
[register + offset        ]
[register          + label]
[register                 ]
[           offset + label]
[           offset        ]
[                    label]
```

The grammar for which might be written:

```
address      = '[' (register ('+' offset-label)? | offset-label) ']'
offset-label = offset ('+' label)? | label
```

Which in Applicative style is pretty straightforward, made only slightly noisy by wrapping everything in constructors:

```
parseAddress :: Parser Address
parseAddress = do
  (register, (offset, label)) <- between (char '[') (char ']') parseRegisterOffsetLabel
  return $ Address register offset label

parseRegisterOffsetLabel :: Parser (Maybe Register, (Maybe Offset, Maybe Label))
parseRegisterOffsetLabel = choice
  [ (,)
    <$> (Just <$> parseRegister)
    <*> option (Nothing, Nothing) (char '+' *> parseOffsetLabel)
  , (,) Nothing <$> parseOffsetLabel
  ]

parseOffsetLabel :: Parser (Maybe Offset, Maybe Label)
parseOffsetLabel = choice
  [ (,)
    <$> (Just <$> parseOffset)
    <*> option Nothing (char '+' *> (Just <$> parseLabel))
  , (,) Nothing . Just <$> parseLabel
  ]
```

If we add a couple of utility functions:

```
plus :: Parser a -> Parser a
plus x = char '+' *> x

just :: Parser a -> Parser (Maybe a)
just = fmap Just
```

We can clean up these implementations a bit:

```
parseRegisterOffsetLabel = choice
  [ (,)
    <$> just parseRegister
    <*> option (Nothing, Nothing) (plus parseOffsetLabel)
  , (,) Nothing <$> parseOffsetLabel
  ]

parseOffsetLabel = choice
  [ (,)
    <$> just parseOffset
    <*> option Nothing (plus (just parseLabel))
  , (,) Nothing <$> just parseLabel
  ]
```

Then factor out the repetition, giving us a decent final solution:

```
parseChain begin def rest = choice
  [ (,) <$> just begin <*> option def (plus rest)
  , (,) Nothing <$> rest
  ]

parseRegisterOffsetLabel = parseChain
  parseRegister (Nothing, Nothing) parseOffsetLabel

parseOffsetLabel = parseChain
  parseOffset Nothing (just parseLabel)
```

I’ll let you take care of whitespace around `+` and inside `[]`.

Comment: Nice one. I modified a bit to fit to my problem. The editing I've done:

I created a `tuple :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser (a,b)` combinator earlier and used it, so applicative `<$>` and `<*>` are not necesarry. 

Used `symbol "+"` to handle white spaces.
And had default values for offsets (the 0 offset) and registers (the $0 register that is always 0), so I use them instead of Nothing.

Comment: @BoldizsárNémeth: Glad to be of help. I could only offer a general solution because I didn’t know your datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
parsePlus = many1 (char ' ') >> char '+' >> many1 (char ' ')

parseRegisterModified = parsePlus >> parseOffsetLabel

parseOffsetModified = parsePlus >> parseLabel

parseRegister' = do
    Address r _ _ <- parseRegister 
    optionMaybe parseRegisterModified >>=
    return $ maybe 
           (Address r Nothing Nothing) 
           (\Address _ o l -> Address r o l) 

parseOffset' = do
    Address _ o _ <- parseOffset 
    optionMaybe parseOffsetModified >>=
    return $ maybe 
           (Address Nothing o Nothing) 
           (\Address _ _ l -> Address Nothing o l)

parseOffsetLabel = try parseOffset' <|> parseLabel

parseAddress = 
     try parseRegister'
     <|> parseOffset'
     <|> parseLabel
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the correct parser, but its a heavyweight solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for something like that and found
[`Control.Applicative.Permutation` from `action-permutations`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/action-permutations-0.0.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative-Permutation.html#g:3). Though my case may scale independently from low-level platform.

In your case might look like

```
operand = do
    (r, o, l) <- runPermsSep (char '+') $ (,,)
        <$> maybeAtom register
        <*> maybeAtom offset
        <*> maybeAtom label
    -- backtrack on inappropriate combination
    when (null $ catMaybes [r, o, l]) . fail $ "operand expected"
    return (r, o, l)
```

Note that you actually want optional permutation parser that requires at least one optional element to be present which makes your wanted parsers combinator pretty specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could have more elegant solution using `Monoids` and `sepBy1`.

But it allows to write `[register + register]` (in our case adding them both)

```
parsePlus = many1 (char ' ') >> char '+' >> many1 (char ' ')

parseAddress1 = 
     try parseRegister
     <|> parseOffset
     <|> parseLabel

parseAddress = sepBy1 parsePlus parseAddress1 >>= return . mconcat

instance Monoid Address where
   mempty  = Address Nothing Nothing Nothing
   Address r o l `mappend` Address r' o' l' = 
           Address (r `mappendA` r') (o `mappendA` o') (l `mappendA` l')
   where
         a `mappendA` a' = fmap getSum $ fmap Sum a `mappend` fmap Sum a'
```

Choosing Monoid (`Sum a`, `First a`, `Last a`) for `r` `o` `l`, we change the behavior:

`Sum` adds each other, `First` chooses first one, `Last` chooses the last one

```
   ... where
      a `mappendA` a' = getFirst $ First a `mappend` First a'
```

Comment: It is interesting, but allowing `[register + register]` is not acceptable.